# responsive grid (grid-template-columns)

Tags: css, flexbox, responsive-design, grid, media-queries

Hello i'm getting used to grid in css and i've used the

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(400px, 1fr));
```

a lot of times, but what if i want the divs inside to start with a specific width? I have something like this

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="right-content">

    </div>
    <div class="left-content">

    </div>
</div>

.wrapper{
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(400px, 1fr));
    }
```

how do i say that the starting size of the .right-content should be 70% of the .wrapper, cuz if i do width 70% he gets the 70% of the 1fr tha the template columns property gives to him....is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If we're just focusing on *left* and *right* content, then perhaps `repeat(auto-fit, minmax(...))` is overcomplicating things.

> When the repeat() function is set to auto-fit or auto-fill, the grid container creates as many grid tracks (columns/rows) as possible without overflowing the container.

Since we only want **2** columns, maybe `grid-template-columns: 1fr minmax(70%, 1fr)` is what you're looking for.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr minmax(70%, 1fr);
}

.right-content {
  background-color: red;
}

.left-content {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left-content"></div>
  <div class="right-content"></div>
</div>
```